# Issue using Ajax to add to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried posting this but it flagged as php so I'm hoping this time it will be ajax or Jquery to hopefully get more responses.

I've been having an issue with my Ajax add function for about a week now. The code I am using for this works in another application with no issues. I'm hoping someone can see if I've made any mistakes or what could be causing it. I've been able to add items to the database via cURL commands with no issue so it isn't the PHP code but I will include that as well for 100% clarity. I am using the Slim Framework

PHP Code

```
$app->post('/addItems/', 'addItems');
function addItems()
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $q = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO items(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9) VALUES (:item1, :item2, :item3, :item4, :item5, :item6, :item7, :item8, :item9)";
    try{
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("item1", $q->item1);
        $stmt->bindParam("item2", $q->item2);
        $stmt->bindParam("item3", $q->item3);
        $stmt->bindParam("item4", $q->item4);
        $stmt->bindParam("item5", $q->item5);
        $stmt->bindParam("item6", $q->item6);
        $stmt->bindParam("item7", $q->item7);
        $stmt->bindParam("item8", $q->item8);
        $stmt->bindParam("item9", $q->item9);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Ajax

```
$("#send").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: addProject(),
        url: rootURL + "/addItems/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("Data Added");
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});

function addProject()
{
    return JSON.stringify({
    "item1": item1,
    "item2": item2,
    "item3": item3,
    "item4": item4,
    "item5": item5,
    "item6": item6,
    "item7": item7,
    "item8": item8,
    "item9": item9,
    });
}
```

All item variables have strings assigned to them

Any help would be appreciated.

Mike

Comment: What is the issue you're having? Ajax doesn't work? Server receives the data but then items not added to DB Or ...???

Comment: So what's the issue? What have you done to narrow it down? Look at the browser's developer tools. Are there errors in the console? Is the request formatted the way you expect? Does $request->getBody() give the value you expect if you echo it? What about $q->item1? Does the PDO Exception fire? What error does it raise?

Comment: It shoots straight to error. As far as I can tell it reaches dataType but it bypasses success. The PHP works perfectly as I stated in the OP. The issue is in the Ajax but I have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: "it shoots straight to error". What does the console in the developer tools say? What does the Net tab show - is the request event made? What happens if you actually look at the three arguments that jQuery will pass into the error function?

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver to develop and test these in which I don't have a console for reports. I should move it to Eclipse or Android Studio but I find it easier in DW

Comment: Test it in a browser. They have developer tools. Standing around moaning that you like DW but DW is rubbish isn't going to help you.

Comment: It turns out the ajax was always working. It was adding it to a database but because it was constantly throwing our the error alert I assumed it wasn't working. I don't know why it was throwing the alert out but I might need to use a browser to test from now on so I can avoid this in the future or just check the DB in the off chance it did work :)

Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a wild guess here but instead of using a function addProject() to return the data in the ajax request itself, can you try calling it before the ajax call and save it to a variable then use that variable instead of the function itself.

Comment: It seems cleaner to use a function. But I will test it out, the thing is that (with a few variable modifications) this same code works for another application.

Comment: I have faced issues in javascript that dont usually happen in our backend languages due to its event driven nature. Do try it once and let me know the results. Thanks

Also, I'm suggesting this assuming that you are not getting the data in the backend using your js code. You have mentioned that cURL works as expected.

Comment: This would be my last suggestion but can you please try hardcoding the data directly without using the function? You can say i have a grudge against functions used like this in js ;) If it doesnt it could be an extremely silly mistake somewhere. You just need to revise your code.

Comment: Okay so apparently it was working the whole time, it was just throwing out the error alert for some reason. I just never checked the database because I assumed it wasn't adding to it due to the error being thrown.